# Why does my code in rand() not work in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

My userid is guid,it is not int.At first,I user `ORDER BY RAND()` and it works.But someone say that it is not efficient.So I try to change it to other ways.But it can not work.How to fix it?

```
-- work fine but not efficient 
select userid from user order by rand() LIMIT 1

-- do not work,always return the same row
 SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid >= ((SELECT MAX(userid) FROM user)
-(SELECT MIN(userid) FROM user)) * RAND() 
+ (SELECT MIN(userid) FROM _user) LIMIT 1

-- do not work,always return the same row
SELECT userid FROM user AS t1 JOIN (SELECT  RAND()
* (SELECT MAX(userid) FROM user) AS id) AS t2 
WHERE t1.userid >= t2.id
ORDER BY t1.userid ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are treating a `guid` as an integer.  That just isn't going to work.  The problem is not `rand()`, it is mistreatment of types.

One method that can make the query more efficient is to do something like this:

```
select userid
from user
where rand() < 0.01
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

This takes about 1% of your table and uses that for sorting.  You can actually formalize this to something like:

```
select userid
from user cross join (select count(*) as cnt from user) params
where rand() < 100 / cnt
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

This will select about 100 rows from the table and sort those.  Sorting 100 rows is not particularly intensive, so that should be reasonable performance-wise.  And, with an expected value of 100 rows, the query should basically never fail to get at least one row.